# Chef: no password provided in the sftp URI

Tags: chef-infra, sftp, chef-recipe

I have the following resource in my cookbook

```
remote_file '/tmp/test.txt' do
  source 'sftp://root@xyz.imzcloud.local:22/tmp/test.txt'
end
```

where I am trying to get a file on a remote host onto the chef-client. chef-client can ssh to the remote_host without password (using ssh key). When I run this recipe I get `no password provided in the sftp URI`. How can get a file through sftp without providing password?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot, see https://github.com/chef/chef/blob/a3a9e92568e663c8fbbbb47010929ea3eef49cab/lib/chef/provider/remote_file/sftp.rb#L82-L93. The SFTP feature in `remote_file` is very rarely used so it's seen little development beyond "it exists".

Comment: So what is the best way to get a file from a remote_host?

Comment: There is no single answer to that. It depends on context and use case.